# Is there a working Corona SDK implementation of the Spriter XML animation format?

Tags: xml, animation, sdk, sprite, coronasdk

The only implementation of Spriter animations within Corona SDK that I could locate was originally developed in 2012 (which was before the public 1.0 release of Spriter, if I am not mistaken), with a few simple updates merged in 2013.

The implementation is mentioned here:
https://brashmonkey.com/forum/index.php?/topic/2791-corona-sdk/#comment-6565

The code itself can be located on GitHub, here:
https://github.com/XibalbaStudios/Spriter

Looking at the .scml format included with the GitHub version, it appears to be very different from the latest Spriter .scml format.

For instance, the old format includes an attribute for generator_version of "a2", whereas the newer format uses "r6".

Running the example code from GitHub within the Corona SDK Simulator using a newer format .scml XML file results in many errors, such as the first located in utils.lua on line 133: "attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value".

Writing a new implementation may be the only answer, but I thought it would be a good idea to ask the community of Corona SDK developers before jumping in, in case someone has already tackled this problem and is willing to share the solution.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Of note, I managed to get this working in a rudimentary way with a couple of dirty hacks after doing the following:

1) I removed all <obj_info> tags from the .scml file
2) In spriter_imp/object.lua, I forced the scaling of objects to be ignored (lines 155 - 162). This means flipped images are not supported. I'll continue to take a stab at getting this properly implemented and provide an answer here if I come up with something useful.